# ggplot2 geom_count set legend breaks to integers

Tags: r, ggplot2, count, legend

I want to use the geom_count graph from ggplot2 but with a too small range in values the legend breaks become floating points for counts of occurances e.g. `1 1.5 2 2.5 3`

Here is a test case:

```
test = mtcars[1:6,]

ggplot(test, aes(cyl, carb)) +
  geom_count(aes(color = ..n.., size = ..n..)) +
  guides(color = 'legend')
```

How can I make the breaks occur only at full integers?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can set the `breaks` for the continuous `color` and `size` scales.

You can give a vector of values for the breaks, but per the documentation the `breaks` argument can also be given:

> a function that takes the limits as input and returns breaks as output

So for a simple case like your example, you could use `as.integer` or `round` as the function.

```
ggplot(test, aes(cyl, carb)) +
     geom_count(aes(color = ..n.., size = ..n..)) +
     guides(color = 'legend') +
     scale_color_continuous(breaks = round) +
     scale_size_continuous(breaks = round)
```

For a larger range of integers than your example, you could either manually enter the breaks, e.g., `breaks = 1:3`, or write a function that takes the limits of the scale and returns a sequence of integers.  You could then use this function for `breaks`.

That could look like:

```
set_breaks = function(limits) {
     seq(limits[1], limits[2], by = 1)
}

ggplot(test, aes(cyl, carb)) +
     geom_count(aes(color = ..n.., size = ..n..)) +
     guides(color = 'legend') +
     scale_color_continuous(breaks = set_breaks) +
     scale_size_continuous(breaks = set_breaks)
```

Comment: Using a vector works thanks, but when I use `round` I lose a value? Here is a test case `test = data.frame(cyl=c(rep(4,3),rep(2,2),1), carb=c(rep(6,3),rep(2,2),5))` where using breaks = round results in breaks at 1 and 3 instead of 1, 2, 3

Comment: This is the only place where I have seen a practical example of what "_A function that takes the limits as input and returns breaks as output_" means exactly. Thank you!

Comment: This function for breaks usually works **pretty** well: `breaks = ~unique(round(pretty(.)))`.